# DynamoDB - GetItem request not working

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I have a table named "***genres***" in DynamoDB.

It has two items so far:

```
| language (Hash Key) | name (Range Key)        |
-------------------------------------------------
| S: "en"             | S: "Comedy"             |
-------------------------------------------------
| S: "es"             | S: "Comedia"            |
```

I'm using **AWSSDK 2.3.44.0** for **.NET**:

```
GetItemRequest request = new GetItemRequest();
request.TableName = "genres";
request.Key = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>()
{
     { "language", new AttributeValue() { S = "en" } },
     { "name", new AttributeValue() { S = "Comedy" } }
}
GetItemResponse response = await _dbClient.GetItemAsync(request);
```

As you can see I am filling all the required information to complete the operation. And in fact, it seems it does so, because no exception is thrown.

However, after inspecting my `response` variable, I see that `response.Item` is empty, as if it didn't find the item in my table, even if all the keys are correct.

I know that maybe `language` and `name` are reserved words, so I tried using [Expression Attribute Names](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_GetItem.html#DDB-GetItem-request-ExpressionAttributeNames) to create the aliases, but the expression names can only be used in expressions, and not in key declarations.

What's happening here?

Comment: I have the same problem! Did you find any solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

try putting other attributes in the row. going to guess it's working - you just don't have anything else to show.

Comment: I tried adding an attribute `test`, but same thing happens. I really don't know what may be going on

Comment: make sure that the schema of your table matches the keys in your request. what happens if you do DescribeTable on genres table?